# Заполнение полей из ссылки в письме

Tags: php, javascript, email, form

Есть сайт с формой добавления скажем "Объявления". Пользователь заполняет форму на сайте, потом данные идут на почту администратору в виде списка, после чего админ проверяет данные и заполняет специальную форму для занесения данных в БД.

Подскажите как можно сделать, может ссылочку в письме, которое приходит с объявлением, при переходе по которой автоматом заполняются поля значениями, после чего просто стоит просмотреть их и подтвердить.

Форма на сайте обычная, типа:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Заготовок" size="45" maxlength="80"/>
<input type="text" name="cat" placeholder="Категория почта" size="45" maxlength="80"/>
<input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Текст" size="45" maxlength="80"/>
</form>
```

Comment: https://site.com/preadd.php?title=Foo&cat=BAR&text=WTF - а дальше уже серверная сторона пускай их отображает и делает с ними что хочет.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, после заполнения пользователем формы вы формируете письмо со ссылкой вида `site.com/preadd.php?title=Foo&cat=BAR&text=WTF`, где в параметрах передаете все введенные данные.

При переходе по ссылке `preadd.php` извлекает из GET-параметров нужные данные, отображает их на админской форме и ждет нажатия на кнопку "добавить" или что там будет, передает эти данные в скрипт добавления.

Второй вариант: данные введенные юзером добавляются в очередь сразу, админ может ее просматривать и принимать решение об удалении/переносе в основную БД. И писем не нужно будет.

Comment: Очередь немоного не подходит - так как приходиться иногда редактировать значения!
http://gamestreamtv.ru/test.php
вот ссылка на демо - подскажите, как их заполнить - потому что не получаеться в виде ссылке той =((

Comment: Можно добавить редактирование данных в очереди, вообще не вопрос. Если вы не знаете что такое PHP и HTML - составляйте ТЗ, фомируйте бюджет и ищите исполнителя.

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы сразу не добавлять в базу данных, только создать дополнительно поле например под именем **active** и когда данные добавляются пользователем в базу в поле **active** записывается **0** ( то есть это объявление не активное и не выводится на экран ).

После чего администратор проверяет данные и может активировать объявление записав в поле **active 1** или редактировать или удалить объявление.

Если будут какие-то вопросы пишите.

Comment: Просто пользователи много разного пишут и приходиться редактировать данные, так что с GET запросоами проще - но не могу понять как их наладить

Comment: Да я понимаю но это не много неправильно с формы отправлять на почту а потом опять в форму и базу данных и post запросами можно гораздо больше передавать информации в отличие от get которые созданы в основном для url адрес. В этом варианте можно сделать когда пользователь редактирует, объявление становится неактивным (и администратору отправляется письмо об объявлении которое нужно просмотреть и активировать) и администратор проверяет и активирует объявления так сделано на всех сайтах объявлений. Если мой вариант был полезен поставь галочку напротив ответа. Успехов.